# Async fetching a minimum number of rows in unpredictable chunk sizes

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I want to retrieve all of the current available documents from an ever-filling queue.  I'm pulling from Amazon's SQS (Simple Queue Service) which asynchronously returns anywhere from 0 to 10 rows per request, which may include duplicates from prior fetches.

Each unique document can be processed asynchronously in parallel, independent of any other document, so that part is conceptually simple to me even with additional async lookups.  Where I'm having trouble is in pulling down the right number of records to process for an overall batch.

Assume I look and see 100 documents in the queue.  If I just do 10 fetches, I might end up with only 50 of the 100 documents... or all 100 if I'm extremely lucky.  If I fetch 1 at a time, I have essentially the same problem-- I might get 0 or 1 or a dupe (it requests round-robin to a cluster of servers).  If have each async fetcher update a common counter, it may spawn hundreds of requests before the first one even knows how many unique documents to count.  How can I determine when to stop fetching additional groups of records from the queue?

Here's a distilled version of the failing code:

```
libutil.countOffers(function(err, data) {
  processEvents(~~data.Attributes.ApproximateNumberOfMessages);
});

function processEvents(count) {
  while (count > 0) {
    libutil.receiveOffers(10, function(err, offers) {
      if (offers && offers.Messages) {
        count-=offers.Messages.length;
        // ^ Broken because async receiveOffers runs hundreds of
        //   times before count is incremented the first time. 
      }
    });
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
libutil.countOffers(function(err, data) {
  processEvents(~~data.Attributes.ApproximateNumberOfMessages);
});

function processEvents(count) {
    libutil.receiveOffers(10, function(err, offers) {
      if (offers && offers.Messages) {
        count-=offers.Messages.length;
        if(count > 0){
          processEvents(count)
        }
      }
    });      
}
```

Your while loop will not wait for the count to be incremented in async callback. So use recursive function or a promise.

Comment: I like this solution, although it may mean I recurse thousands of times in one batch.

Comment: That should be fine. Stack size is usually of range 16000.

Comment: Thank you.  I think this approach will work fine for small batches, which does meet my current needs.  I'd still like to learn a more conservative stream-like way of processing the queue.  It bugs me that this performs all requests and then works its way through the retrieved documents in reverse order.